# Components created using styled-components with Semantic UI React aren't retaining the SUIR component's props type information

Tags: typescript, styled-components, semantic-ui-react

Components created using styled-components with Semantic UI React aren't retaining the props types from the original SUIR component.

## Without styled-components

Without styled-components the SUIR components props type information is retained.

```js
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
<Button onClick={(e) => alert("hi")}>Submit</Button>
```

onClick is typed as

```js
onClick?: ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>, data: ButtonProps) => void) | undefined
```

Intellisense will then show me the available props in Visual Studio Code and their type.

[image: Display onClick prop]

[image: Display type information for onClick]

## With styled-components

When I use styled-components the type information for the SUIR component's props is lost.

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  color: red !important;
`;

<StyledButton onClick={(e) => alert("hi")}>Submit</StyledButton >
```

onClick is now inferred from the function I assigned it and is typed as ...

```js
onClick?: (e: any) => void
```

Intellisense cannot find the available props nor the appropriate type

[image: Cannot see available props]

[image: Incorrect (inferred) type]

I tried providing the props type to the styled component as shown below, but it had no effect.

```js
const StyledSUIRButton = styled(Button)<ButtonProps>`
  color: red !important;
`;
```

Props for my own custom function and class components work fine, so I am a bit baffled. There is something about the intersection of SUIR and styled-components that is causing the type information for the props to be lost.

Here is a live example demonstrating the issue
https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-removes--giv1m

I have also posted the question here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/49962

Any suggestions for how to surface Semantic UI React props in Styled Components?

Answer (score 2):

This is a workaround, I don't think it should be the longterm solution—if you re-declare the props again, they will become known to the extended component and Intellisense will find them again.

```
import { Button, ButtonProps } from "semantic-ui-react";

// const StyledSUIRButton = styled(Button)``
const StyledSUIRButton: React.FC<ButtonProps> = styled(Button)``
```

For your example, this works great.

For components extended with additional props, or extending an already extended component, this becomes cumbersome.

Comment: This one works. Other solutions like putting `as typeof ButtonProps` at the end of definitions doesn't work for semantic UI.